# How can I show a dialog to take a picture or choose a picture from gallery

Tags: android

I need to make a app where you can take pictures and load pictures from your gallery.
I can take pictures and load it on the screen and I can take pictures from the gallery, but I have 2 buttons now. My question is how can I 'popup a dialog' where you can take a picture or import a picture from the gallery.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView imageView;
    Button btnTakeImg;
    Uri imageUri;



    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnCamera = findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnTakeImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTakeImg);



        // Open camera and take picture
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });



        // Pick image from gallery
        btnTakeImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });

    }
    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0){
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link [Util class to pick image from gallery or from camera](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2)

Edit 1 : 
To capture image from Camera

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
```

To pick from gallery

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
```

Processing the result :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
switch(requestCode) {
case 0:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        imageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
    }

break; 
case 1:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        imageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
    }
break;
}
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22980340)

Comment: Modified my answer